# Circle of apples and oranges

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

7 identical apples and 13 identical oranges are to be arranged in a circle so that no two apples are consecutive.
No.of ways of doing it is?

I do know about circular permutations and clockwise, anticlockwise arrangements but here the apples and oranges are identical .

Comment: This is analogous to this [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051303/no-of-polygons-in-a-polygon-with-no-side-coinciding). See also the linked and related questions there. You are looking for the number of 7-sided polygons formed from the vertices of a 20-sided polygon with no sides common.

Comment: Try modifying my solution to this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3120693/seating-six-boys-and-four-girls-around-a-table-so-that-no-two-girls-can-sit-next/3120772#3120772).  The principal difference between the problems is that boys and girls are distinct while fruits of the same type are treated as identical in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

There must at least be one orange between two apples. As a result, we must use $7$ apples and $7$ oranges (circular permutation).

How many spots are there left for the $6$ remaining oranges? Therefore how many combinations are there?